# Is there any command to make the math symbol "not equal" appear in a string?

Tags: python, string, math, printing, ironpython

For example, to print the greek letter alpha I used `\u03B1` and the output is:

`α`

Now I want to print not equal like this:

`≠`

Comment: Look up the Unicode code for the symbol

Comment: You can just write `print("3 ≠ 5")`.

Comment: If you can type or paste "≠" in your code editor, then you don't need to do anything more than what mkrieger1 said, but FYI: `\u03B1` is Python syntax that specifies a _unicode code point_ using only ASCII characters. If you Google for "unicode lower case alpha" the first thing you'll see will be the official Unicode representation of the same thing, "U+03B1". Now google for "unicode not equal sign" and you should be able to figure out what to do next.  To learn more, see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
u"\u2260"
```

**source**: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2260/index.htm

You could obtain most UTF encodings with a google search :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following :

```
print(u'\u2260')
```